# Unable to target h1 in span class

Tags: html, css

I have a span class that I’m attempting to target the H1 in to style however its not working.

Here is my html.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                <span class="testimonial"><h1>Testimonial</h1></span>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.testimonial h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Am I not using the CSS correctly?

Comment: It works fine to me.. Can you explain what doesn't work?  http://jsfiddle.net/6rL1tsed/ You could use inspect elements to see whats going wrong..

Comment: Should be working just fine.. : http://jsfiddle.net/bfgrebgc/

Comment: It is correct. Maybe there is conflict in other parts

Comment: Are you sure you're including the css file properly?

Comment: Is it possible some other CSS is potentially interfering with this?

Comment: post the entire style sheet.. Some other style is over-riding this

Comment: Is this the HTML from your file or the actual output?

Comment: Use your browser's DOM inspector to see what rules are being applied to those elements. it could be something like a `!important` rule elsewhere overriding your css as posted here.

Comment: My guess is rather that this is in the HTML file but the browser renders it differently since block elements (h1) are not allowed inside inline elements (span). Thus, the actual output won't have a `h1` inside `.testimonial`. At least, some editors like CKEditor filter such constructs.

Comment: It seems fine. Can you give a screenshot of your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
.col-md-9 .testimonial h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a specificity issue have you tried:

```
div.col-md-9>span.testimonial>h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you linking fine css file?

It worked for me, and it's exactly your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .testimonial h1 {
            font-size: 16px; font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <span class="testimonial">
            <h1>Testimonial</h1>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```